# Sorting container of tuples by fixed components

Tags: c++, sorting, templates, c++11

Given a container of pairs or tuples, we want to sort it by specifying a binary predicate and a fixed component, so that the sorting focusses only on that component of each tuple.  This working code illustrates this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

template <int N, typename BinaryPredicate, typename ForwardIterator>
void sortByFixedComponent (ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last) {
    std::sort (first, last, [](const typename ForwardIterator::value_type& x, const typename ForwardIterator::value_type& y)->bool {
        return BinaryPredicate()(std::get<N>(x), std::get<N>(y));
    });
}

// ------------------- Testing --------------------
struct Length {
    bool operator()(const std::string& a, const std::string& b) const {return a.length() < b.length();}
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> v = {
        {3,5}, {6,8}, {3,7}, {1,9}, {3,1}, {1,2}, {3,5}
    };
    sortByFixedComponent<0, std::less<int>> (v.begin(), v.end());  // Sorts v according to the first components.
    for (const std::pair<int,int>& x : v) std::cout << "(" << x.first << ", " << x.second << ") ";  std::cout << '\n';
    sortByFixedComponent<1, std::greater<int>> (v.begin(), v.end());  // Sorts v according to the second components (in reverse order).
    for (const std::pair<int,int>& x : v) std::cout << "(" << x.first << ", " << x.second << ") ";  std::cout << '\n';

    using Tuple = std::tuple<int, std::string, char>;
    std::vector<Tuple> t = {
        Tuple{3,"hi",'q'}, Tuple{6,"dog",'u'}, Tuple{3,"hello",'c'}, Tuple{1,"cat",'r'}, Tuple{3,"no",'a'}, Tuple{1,"orange",'z'}, Tuple{3,"door",'x'}
    };
    sortByFixedComponent<1, Length> (t.begin(), t.end());  // Sorts t according to the second components in order of string lengths.
}
```

The challenge now are the ties (tuples that are tied in that specified component).  So let us put into `sortByFixedComponent` the packs `Z<Is...>` and `P<BinaryPredicates...>` that will determine the sorting among the ties.  In the above example, there are ties, so go to the next int in `Is...` and the next binary predicate in `BinaryPredicates...` and sort among those ties in this new fixed component and new binary predicate.  If there are ties still after this, then keep going through `Is...` and `BinaryPredicates...`.  This should ultimately lead to a unique ordering.

Of course, this recursion is where I'm stuck.  This is what I have so far, which compiles only because I didn't fill in the recursion step yet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

template <typename, typename, typename> struct SortByFixedComponent;

template <template <int...> class Z, int N, template <typename...> class P, typename BinaryPredicate, typename ForwardIterator>
struct SortByFixedComponent<Z<N>, P<BinaryPredicate>, ForwardIterator> {
    void operator()(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last) {
        std::sort (first, last, [](const typename ForwardIterator::value_type& x, const typename ForwardIterator::value_type& y)->bool {
            return BinaryPredicate()(std::get<N>(x), std::get<N>(y));
        });
    }
};

template <template <int...> class Z, int FirstInt, int... RestInt, template <typename...> class P, typename FirstBinaryPredicate, typename... RestBinaryPredicate, typename ForwardIterator>
struct SortByFixedComponent<Z<FirstInt, RestInt...>, P<FirstBinaryPredicate, RestBinaryPredicate...>, ForwardIterator> :
        SortByFixedComponent<Z<RestInt...>, P<RestBinaryPredicate...>, ForwardIterator> {
    void operator()(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last) {
        std::sort (first, last, [](const typename ForwardIterator::value_type& x, const typename ForwardIterator::value_type& y)->bool {
            return FirstBinaryPredicate()(std::get<FirstInt>(x), std::get<FirstInt>(y));
        });
// How to sort among the ties using SortByFixedComponent<Z<RestInt...>, P<RestBinaryPredicate...>, ForwardIterator>::operator()(first, last); ??? 
    }
};

template <typename Ints, typename BinaryPredicates, typename ForwardIterator>
void sortByFixedComponent (ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last) {
    SortByFixedComponent<Ints, BinaryPredicates, ForwardIterator>()(first, last);
}

struct Length {
    bool operator()(const std::string& a, const std::string& b) const {return a.length() < b.length();}
};

template <typename...> struct P {};
template <int...> struct Z {};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> v = {
        {3,5}, {6,8}, {3,7}, {1,9}, {3,1}, {1,2}, {3,5}
    };
    sortByFixedComponent< Z<0>, P<std::less<int>> > (v.begin(), v.end());
    for (const std::pair<int,int>& x : v) std::cout << "(" << x.first << ", " << x.second << ") ";  std::cout << '\n';
    sortByFixedComponent< Z<1>, P<std::greater<int>> > (v.begin(), v.end());
    for (const std::pair<int,int>& x : v) std::cout << "(" << x.first << ", " << x.second << ") ";  std::cout << '\n';

    using Tuple = std::tuple<int, std::string, char>;
    std::vector<Tuple> t = {
        Tuple{3,"hi",'q'}, Tuple{6,"dog",'u'}, Tuple{3,"hello",'c'}, Tuple{1,"cat",'r'}, Tuple{3,"no",'a'}, Tuple{1,"orange",'z'}, Tuple{3,"door",'x'}
    };
    sortByFixedComponent< Z<1>, P<Length> > (t.begin(), t.end());
//  sortByFixedComponent<Z<2,0,1>, P<std::greater<char>, Length, std::less<int>>> (t.begin(), t.end());  // Want this line to work.
}
```

Ultimately, in main() I want the line

```
sortByFixedComponent<Z<2,0,1>, P<std::greater<char>, Length, std::less<int>>> (t.begin(), t.end());
```

to work.  It is to sort the container

```
    std::vector<Tuple> t = {
        Tuple{3,"hi",'q'}, Tuple{6,"dog",'u'}, Tuple{3,"hello",'c'}, Tuple{1,"cat",'r'}, Tuple{3,"no",'a'}, Tuple{1,"orange",'z'}, Tuple{3,"door",'x'}
    };
```

so that the char components are first looked at (sort the tuples so that the these are in alphabetical order), then among the ties look at the int component (sort the ties so that these are in reverse order), then if there are still any ties look at the string component (sort the ties so that the strings are from shortest to longest).
  Any help would be appreciated.  This question arose when I solved the first example, but then wondered about the ties.

To see a concrete example.  In my very first example, the output is (1, 9) (1, 2) (3, 5) (3, 7) (3, 1) (3, 5) (6, 8) because the first components are sorted from least to greatest. But 4 pairs begin with 3. So let's sort these 4 according to the second component by some other comparator. The goal is a generalization of this.

**Update:**
   I think the key to solving this is not recursion, so basically my attempt above can be scrapped.  I think it is composition of the binary predicates that is needed.  So my new starting point is to use this helper struct:

```
template <typename, typename...> struct PredicateBuilder;

template <typename T, typename BinaryPredicate> 
struct PredicateBuilder<T, BinaryPredicate> {
    const BinaryPredicate binaryPredicate;
    PredicateBuilder (BinaryPredicate func): binaryPredicate (func) {}
    bool operator() (const T& a, const T& b) const {return binaryPredicate (a,b);}
};

template <typename T, typename First, typename... Rest>
struct PredicateBuilder<T, First, Rest...> : PredicateBuilder<T, Rest...> {
    const First binaryPredicate;
    PredicateBuilder (First first, Rest... rest): PredicateBuilder<T, Rest...> (rest...), binaryPredicate (first) {}
    bool operator () (const T& a, const T& b) const {
        if (binaryPredicate (a,b))
            return true;
        else if (binaryPredicate (b,a)) 
            return false;
        else
            return PredicateBuilder<T, Rest...>::operator()(a,b);
    }
};
```

Comment: tl;dr aka couldnt find the question

Comment: I clarified my question in the last part.  The char components are first looked at (sort the tuples so that the these are in alphabetical order), then among the ties look at the int component (sort the ties so that these are in reverse order), then if there are still any ties look at the string component (sort the ties so that the strings are from shortest to longest).  If this test in main() passes, then the entire algorithm should be correct.

Comment: I am interested in your question but your code is above my head. A simple English description of what you are trying to do (rather than what you've done so far) would help.

Comment: Ok, we have a container of tuples.  Let's sort them. How?  Let's focus on the 3rd component of each tuple (suppose that is int), and then sort the tuples so that the 3rd components are in reverse order.  But there are some ties (some of the tuples have identical 3rd components).  So let's look at the first component (which is char) and sort the tied groups so that these are in alphabetical order.  Still some ties among these first components and third components, look for another component and continue.

Comment: same for me, but still after your edit I cannot find what is your question. Please try to summarize what is your problem in 1-2 sentences. Actually I still dont find the question in your text

Comment: Can't you just pass a custom comparator which looks at the nth component?

Comment: In my very first example, the output is (1, 9) (1, 2) (3, 5) (3, 7) (3, 1) (3, 5) (6, 8) because the first components are sorted from least to greatest.  But 4 pairs begin with 3.  So let's sort these 4 according to the second component by some other comparator. The goal is a generalization of this.

Comment: @Neil Kirk. I did that already in my first example.  So now I want to continue with all the other components by specifying the order of the components for each subsequent sort, and the binary predicates that go with those components to carry out those sorts.

Comment: I think it is composing the comparators that needs to be done, instead of recursion.  I've added a new idea and a new approach in my question.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class F>
struct order_by_t {
  F f;
  template<class Lhs, class Rhs>
  bool operator(Lhs&&lhs, Rhs&&rhs)const {
    return f(std::forward<Lhs>(lhs)) < f(std::forward<Rhs>(rhs));
  }
};
template<class F>
order_by_t< std::decay_t<F> > order_by( F&& f ) {
  return {std::forward<F>(f)};
}
```

This takes a type T and a map M:T->U and uses the ordering on U to provide an ordering on T.

```
template<size_t... Is>
struct retie {
  template<class Tup>
  auto operator()( Tup&& tup )const->
  decltype(std::tie( std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tup>(tup))... ))
  { return std::tie( std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tup>(tup))... ); }
};
```

this takes a tuple `tup` and reties its elements in a different order.

```
std::sort( foo.begin(), foo.end(), order_by( retie<3,2,1>{} ) );
```

will sort `foo` via element 3, then element 2, then element 1.

The next thing you want to be able to do is to project each sub element into its own sorting domain.  Still not what you want, but closer.

To solve this, I'd work on piping and making a variardic `order_by`.

Piping lets you get, then project to a new space.

```
template<class... Fs>
struct order_by_t;

template<>
struct order_by_t<> {
  template<class Lhs, class Rhs>
  bool operator(Lhs&&lhs, Rhs&&rhs)const {
    return false;
  }
};
template<class F>
struct order_by_t<F> {
  F f;
  template<class Lhs, class Rhs>
  bool operator(Lhs&&lhs, Rhs&&rhs)const {
    return f(std::forward<Lhs>(lhs)) < f(std::forward<Rhs>(rhs));
  }
};
template<class F, class...Fs>
struct order_by_t<F, Fs...>:
  order_by<Fs...>
{
  template<class T, class...Ts>
  order_by_t(T&&t, Ts&&...ts):
    order_by_t<Fs...>{std::forward<Ts>(ts)...},
    f(std::forward<T>(t))
  {}
  F f;
  template<class Lhs, class Rhs>
  bool operator(Lhs&&lhs, Rhs&&rhs)const {
    auto&& lhs_ = f(lhs);
    auto&& rhs_ = f(rhs);
    if (lhs_<rhs_) return true;
    if (rhs_<lhs_) return false;
    return order_by_t<Fs...>::operator()
      (std::forward<Lhs>(lhs),std::forward<Rhs>(rhs));
  }
};
template<class... Fs>
order_by_t< std::decay_t<Fs>... > order_by( Fs&&... fs ) {
  return {std::forward<Fs>(fs)...};
}
```

now `order_by` can take a collection of projections, and it projects one at a time, picking the first to use.

Now we want to pipe operations together, so the get projection can be followed by a length projection (for example).

```
template<size_t I>
struct get_t {
  template<class Tup>
  auto operator()(Tup&&tup)const->
  decltype(std::get<I>(tup))
  { return std::get<I>(tup); }
};
template<class A, class B>
struct compose_t {
  A a; B b;
  template<class... Ts>
  auto operator()(Ts&&...ts)const->
  std::result_of_t< A const&( std::result_of_T< B const&(Ts...) > ) >
  {
    return a(b(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...));
  }
  // if you have a SFINAE enabled result_of, this is also useful.
  // if you don't, don't include this overload (it isn't used in this code):
  #if 0
  template<class... Ts>
  auto operator()(Ts&&...ts)const->
  std::result_of_t< A const&( std::result_of_T< B const&(Ts) >... ) >
  {
    return a(b(std::forward<Ts>(ts))...);
  }
  #endif
};
template<class A, class B>
compose_t< std::decay_t<A>, std::decay_t<B> >
compose(A&& a, B&& b) {
  return {std::forward<A>(a), std::forward<B>(b)};
}
```

and we are almost there!  Replace your `Length` with:

```
struct get_length {
  size_t operator()( std::string const& s ) const {
    return s.size();
  }
};
struct reversed_sort_t {
  template<class T>
  struct helper {
    T&& t;
    template<class A, class B>
    friend bool operator<(helper<A>&& lhs, helper<B>&& rhs) {
      return std::forward<B>(rhs.t) < std::forward<A>(lhs.t);
    }
  };
  template<class T>
  helper<T> operator()(T&& t) const {
    return {std::forward<T>(t)};
  }
};

//  sortByFixedComponent<Z<2,0,1>, P<std::greater<char>, Length, std::less<int>>> (t.begin(), t.end());  // Want this line to work.
auto ordering = order_by(
  compose( reversed_sort_t{}, get_t<2>{} ),
  compose( get_length{}, get_t<0>{} ),
  get_t<1>{}
);
std::sort( t.begin(), t.end(), ordering );
```

A slightly different approach would be to chain multiple full orderings together, instead of chaining `order_by` projections onto each other.

If you really want your specific syntax, work can be done to extract the `I` and the `F` and pair them up and build an `ordering` function call.

None of the above is compiled or tested, but the design should work.

I find the projecting your data into an already defined domain with a well defined `<` is usually more pleasing than writing a custom comparison operator.

The above uses a handful of C++14 features, mostly `_t` aliases.  Replace `std::blah_t< args >` with `typename std::blah< args >::type` if you lack that alias, or write your own `_t` alias like `template<class...Ts> using blah_t=typename std::blah<Ts...>::type;`.  There is also some code that is much improved by the C++14 `std::result_of`, with the improvement `#if 0`'d out currently.

The strangest order mapping is `reversed_sort_t`, which maps `T->reversed_sort_t::helper<T>`, where `helper<T>` is a type that supports nothing except reference-semantics default copy and reverses the application of `<`.  An older version of this solution negated, but negation of -128 doesn't produce +128 when restricted to `char`.

Comment: I was busy working on my new idea when you posted your solution.  I haven't studied your idea yet, but I will do so and try to make it fully compile once I understand it, and then see if it is vastly different from my solution or not.  Regardless, you definitely get my vote for believing in my question and your willingness to help out.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

template <typename, typename, typename> struct TuplePredicateBuilder;

template <template <int...> class Z, int N, template <typename...> class P, typename BinaryPredicate, typename Iterator>
struct TuplePredicateBuilder<Z<N>, P<BinaryPredicate>, Iterator> {
    bool operator()(const typename Iterator::value_type& x, const typename Iterator::value_type& y) {
        return BinaryPredicate()(std::get<N>(x), std::get<N>(y));
    }
};

template <template <int...> class Z, int FirstInt, int... RestInt, template <typename...> class P, typename FirstBinaryPredicate, typename... RestBinaryPredicate, typename Iterator>
struct TuplePredicateBuilder<Z<FirstInt, RestInt...>, P<FirstBinaryPredicate, RestBinaryPredicate...>, Iterator> : TuplePredicateBuilder<Z<RestInt...>, P<RestBinaryPredicate...>, Iterator> {
    bool operator()(const typename Iterator::value_type& x, const typename Iterator::value_type& y) {
        if (FirstBinaryPredicate()(std::get<FirstInt>(x), std::get<FirstInt>(y)))
            return true;
        else if (FirstBinaryPredicate()(std::get<FirstInt>(y), std::get<FirstInt>(x)))
            return false;
        else
            return TuplePredicateBuilder<Z<RestInt...>, P<RestBinaryPredicate...>, Iterator>::operator()(x,y);
    }
};

template <typename, typename, typename> struct SortByFixedComponent;

template <template <int...> class Z, int N, template <typename...> class P, typename BinaryPredicate, typename Iterator>
struct SortByFixedComponent<Z<N>, P<BinaryPredicate>, Iterator> {
    void operator()(Iterator first, Iterator last) {
        std::sort (first, last, [](const typename Iterator::value_type& x, const typename Iterator::value_type& y)->bool {
            return BinaryPredicate()(std::get<N>(x), std::get<N>(y));
        });
    }
};

template <template <int...> class Z, int... Is, template <typename...> class P, typename... BinaryPredicates, typename Iterator>
struct SortByFixedComponent<Z<Is...>, P<BinaryPredicates...>, Iterator> {
    void operator()(Iterator first, Iterator last) {
        std::sort (first, last, [](const typename Iterator::value_type& x, const typename Iterator::value_type& y)->bool {
            return TuplePredicateBuilder<Z<Is...>, P<BinaryPredicates...>, Iterator>()(x,y);
        });
    }
};

template <typename Components, typename BinaryPredicates, typename Iterator>
void sortByFixedComponent (Iterator first, Iterator last) {
    SortByFixedComponent<Components, BinaryPredicates, Iterator>()(first, last);
}
```

Testing the output:

```
struct Length {
    bool operator()(const std::string& a, const std::string& b) const {return a.length() < b.length();}
};

template <typename...> struct P {};
template <int...> struct Z {};

template <typename Tuple, std::size_t N>
struct TuplePrinter {
    static void print(const Tuple& t) {
        TuplePrinter<Tuple, N-1>::print(t);
        std::cout << ", " << std::get<N-1>(t);
    }
};

template <typename Tuple>
struct TuplePrinter<Tuple, 1>{
    static void print (const Tuple& t) {std::cout << std::get<0>(t);}
};

template <typename... Args>
void print (const std::tuple<Args...>& t) {
    std::cout << "(";
    TuplePrinter<decltype(t), sizeof...(Args)>::print(t);
    std::cout << ")\n";
}

int main() {
    using Tuple = std::tuple<std::string, int, char>;
    std::vector<Tuple> t = {
        Tuple{"hi",3,'q'}, Tuple{"dog",6,'u'}, Tuple{"hello",3,'c'}, Tuple{"cat",1,'u'}, Tuple{"no",3,'a'}, Tuple{"orange",1,'u'}, Tuple{"red",3,'u'}
    };
    sortByFixedComponent<Z<2,0,1>, P<std::greater<char>, Length, std::less<int>>> (t.begin(), t.end());
    for (const Tuple& x : t)
        print(x);
}
```

Output:

```
(cat, 1, u)
(red, 3, u)
(dog, 6, u)
(orange, 1, u)
(hi, 3, q)
(hello, 3, c)
(no, 3, a)
```

First the 3rd component is arranged in reverse alphabetical order.  Then among these 4 tuples ending in u, the string component is arranged from shortest to longest.  There are still three ties, so among these the int component is arranged from least to greatest.  I hope those reading before understand my question now.

I will study Yakk's solution now to see if his method is really different or not.

Update:  I just want to add that I found a more general way to write the above (tested to give the exact same output), using:

```
// General predicate builder so that other types than TuplePredicateBuilder can inherit from this as well.
template <typename, typename...> struct PredicateBuilder;

template <typename T, typename BinaryPredicate> 
struct PredicateBuilder<T, BinaryPredicate> {
    bool operator()(const T& a, const T& b) const {return BinaryPredicate()(a,b);}
};

template <typename T, typename First, typename... Rest>
struct PredicateBuilder<T, First, Rest...> : PredicateBuilder<T, Rest...> {
    bool operator()(const T& a, const T& b) const {
        if (First()(a,b))
            return true;
        else if (First()(b,a)) 
            return false;
        else
            return PredicateBuilder<T, Rest...>::operator()(a,b);
    }
};

template <int N, typename BinaryPredicate, typename Iterator>
struct BinaryPredicateNthComponent {
    bool operator()(const typename Iterator::value_type& x, const typename Iterator::value_type& y) {
        return BinaryPredicate()(std::get<N>(x), std::get<N>(y));
    }
};

template <typename, typename, typename> struct TuplePredicateBuilder;

template <template <int...> class Z, int... Is, template <typename...> class P, typename... BinaryPredicates, typename Iterator>
struct TuplePredicateBuilder<Z<Is...>, P<BinaryPredicates...>, Iterator> : 
    PredicateBuilder<typename Iterator::value_type, BinaryPredicateNthComponent<Is, BinaryPredicates, Iterator>...> {};
```